# Shell scripting: grep and tab delimited

Tags: shell, grep

I am using following command to look for strings in given tab delimited file and count the number of times the string appears.

```
grep -c "string1" filename; grep -c "string2" filename; grep -c "string3" filename
```

In the above command, string1, 2, 3 are the ones I am looking for their occurrence (actually counting how many time do they occur) in file **`filename`**.

I would like to have the output send to a file in a tab delimited format (this will obviously mean new filename) .

I am new to shell scripting and your help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using 2 strings just for example:

```
echo -e "`grep -c 'string1' filename`\t`grep -c 'string2' filename`" > output
```

You can add the date and append to the existing output like this:

```
echo -e "`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`\t`grep -c 'string1' filename`" >> output
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. one last question. How I can also add a head to this output file. for example. It should also bear the current date before this operation (echo -e "`grep -c 'string1' filename`\t`grep -c 'string2' filename`" > output) and if this operation is repeated again a new file should not be formed but the next output be added beneath the previous one.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of including a date column and append to the existing file (reduced to one string to fit better).

Comment: Date and string search output have to be in two different lines. I have tried `\n` instead of `\t`... it gives an error

Comment: echo -e "`$i `\n` 'AP1' `\n` grep -c 'AP1' motifcount`" >> outputmotifcount this what I am doing. To brief you line 1 of output should contain the region which is stored in $i line 2 is the name of the string searched for and line 3 gives the number of times that string appears.

Comment: Hey Thank you, I have solved the problem it was a very small mistake. Thank you for your help.